# Zeros of Fourier-type integral

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose you have a function $f$ in $L^1$. Now let
$$
F_s(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\sin( s \cdot t)\,\mathrm dt
$$
According to the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma we can tell that
$$
\lim_{s\to \infty}F_s(x) = 0
$$
(pointwise).

Can I use that fact in order to tell that for each fixed $x$ there is an infinite set $S_x$ of values of $s(x)$ such that $F_{s(x)}(x)=0$? And is there a (more or less) explicit way to exhibit that set $S_x$?

EDIT: Fixed notation

Comment: Why do you think it has some zeros $\ne 0$ ? ($G(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t) e^{i \omega t}dt, g(t) = g(-t) \in \mathbb{R}, g \in C^\infty_c$ can have no real zeros, so that $G(\omega) (\sin( \omega)+i\sin(\pi \omega))$ has only one real zero)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your comment correctly, but in your case you'll have $G(0) \ne 0$ in general since $g$ is symmetric. I get $G(0) = 2 \int_0^\infty g(t)\,\mathrm dt$. And why should $G$ have no other zeros?

Comment: Have you considered a function $f > 0$ that is strictly decreasing on $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find a counter-example so far. Is there something obvious I'm missing right now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your conjecture is false. 
If $f$ is a positive, decreasing function then $F_s(x)>0$ for all $x>0$:
\begin{align*}
F_s(x)
 &= \int_0^x f(t) \sin(st) \mathrm dt 
 = \int_{t=0}^x \left( f(x)-\int_{u=t}^x \mathrm df(u) \right) \sin(st) \mathrm dt \\
 &= f(x)\int_{t=0}^x \sin(st) \mathrm dt + \int_{u=0}^x \left( \int_{t=0}^u  \sin(st) \mathrm dt \right) \big(-\mathrm df(u)\big) \\
 &= f(x)\frac{1-\cos(sx)}{s} + \int_{u=0}^x \left( \frac{1-\cos(su)}{s}\right) \big(-\mathrm df(u)\big)
 >0.
\end{align*}

A concrete example: if $f(t)=e^{-t}$ then
$$
F_s(x)
 = \left[ \frac{-e^{-t}\big(s\cos(sx)+\sin(sx)\big)}{1+s^2} \right]_0^x
 = \frac{1-e^{-s}\big(s\cos(sx)+\sin(sx)\big)}{1+s^2}>0.
$$

Comment: Great, thank you. Do you have an idea for a proof (or a counterexample) in case $x$ is a zero of $f$? Is it then true that $F_s(x)$ has zeros $s$?

Comment: The same proof works for the function $f(t)=\max(1-t,0)$. So it can be reasonable to constrain that $f$ has both positive and negative values, or at least $f$ is not monotonc.

Comment: Great, thank you.